# what is difference hue execute task in browser and as workflow running

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-yarn, oozie, hue

My task is combined by multiple sql.I copy these sql to window of browser for executing. The task will success.
But I copy sql to file, then edit workflow. I execute workflow, it always has error on specific point.
My sqls include some setting in header.

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
set mapreduce.map.memory.mb=5120;
set mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=5120;
set mapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx4096m;
set mapreduce.reduce.java.opts=-Xmx4096m;

create table as select ......;
create table as select ......;
create table as select ......;
```

Oh, I am surprised by this problem. I don't understand it. anyone help me?

Error info is "... is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 2.0 GB of 2 GB physical memory used; 3.5 GB of 4.2 GB virtual memory used. Killing container". This error happen in map stage.

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: @cricket_007The error is "... is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 2.0 GB of 2 GB physical memory used; 3.5 GB of 4.2 GB virtual memory used. Killing container".

Comment: Sounds like you're going to need more RAM given to your YARN containers

Comment: Hue could be deployed with a custom yarn-site.xml or hive-site.xml, and that could explain the difference

Comment: @cricket_007I guess tow way is different, but I don't understand why. I think it is confusing.

Comment: Your "workflows" run from Oozie, not Hue. Those jobs can have different property files on the YARN servers

Comment: @cricket_007 The same sql and setting have different property files? Could you give me an example?

Comment: Not in your code or queries. On the servers themselves. Probably files out of your control if you're not the Hadoop administrator. All you're doing in this query is overwriting what's defined in those files. If you're running a Cloudera cluster, in theory, there should be no difference between Hue and Oozie workflows running queries, but that's not always the case. What I would do is use beeline from an SSH session to run the same query, because I bet that the issue is actually unrelated to Hue